# Ajax call error in Spring MVC

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, spring

I have a form where I add the customer's informations. This informations are passed to @Controller by an Ajax call.

**Customer.java**

```
public class Customer {

private String name;
private String fiscalCode;
private String vat;
private String telephone;
private String webSite;
private String sector;
private String address;

//Below there are constructor and getter/setter methods
```

**Above the form there is:**

```
<c:set var="serverUrl"    value="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}"/>
<script>
    var serverUrl = '${serverUrl}';
</script>
```

**Form in the jsp**

```
<form>                        
    <div class="form-group">
        <input id="nameCustomer" class="form-control" type="text"     placeholder="Name customer">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">                                
        <input id="fiscalCode" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Fiscal code">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input id="vat" class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="VAT number (if available)">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input id="telephone" class="form-control" type="tel" placeholder="Phone number">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input id="website" class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Customer's Website (if available)">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
         <input id="address" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Customer's Address">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
         <input id="sector" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Sector">
     </div>
     <button id="createCustomer" type="button" class="btn btn-success" style="text-align: center">Save</button>                        
 </form>
```

**Ajax call** (the link to this ajax call code is below the form)

```
$("#createCustomer").click(function () {
    alert("createCustomer");
    alert(serverUrl);
    var nameCustomer = $("#nameCustomer").val();
    var fiscalCode = $("#fiscalCode").val();
    var vat = $("#vat").val();
    var telephone = $("#telephone").val();
    var website = $("#website").val();
    var address = $("#address").val();
    var sector = $("#sector").val();

    alert(address);
    $.ajax({
        url: serverUrl + "/addCustomer",
        dataType: 'text',
        data: {name: nameCustomer, 
               fiscalCode: fiscalCode, 
               vat: vat, 
               telephone: telephone,
               webSite: website,
               address: address,
               sector: sector},
        success: function (data) {
            $("#customerAdded").modal('show');                
        },
        error: function (xhr, error, exception) {
            $("#errorCustomer").modal('show');

        }
    });
});
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
public class CustomerController {

@RequestMapping("addCustomer")
public void addCustomer(@ModelAttribute Customer customer){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, customer.toString());
}
```

Chrome gives me this error:

> http://localhost:8080/ReportVisitaWeb/addCustomer?name=gdg&fiscalCode=dfgdfg&vat=&telephone=dfgg&webSite=dfggf&address=dfgddf&sector=gdg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Why?

Comment: Does the controller get autoscanned correctly? If not, it would be invisible to Spring. Most of the code you posted is irrelevant, seeing Spring MVC configuration would be more useful.

Comment: Success!

I forgot to add 

<context:component-scan base-package="it.jdk.reportvisitaweb.navigation"/> 

in the dispatcher..

Comment: I would've posted this as an answer but it was just a guess based on experience and seeing this asked lots of times already (I couldn't find a "prior art" question to mark this one as duplicate), there's nothing in your question that would lead to this conclusion.

Answer (score -1):

You are not mapping the request "addCustomer" correctly. Edit your `CustomerController` as below:

```
@Controller
public class CustomerController {
            @RequestMapping("/addCustomer")
            public void addCustomer(@ModelAttribute Customer customer){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, customer.toString());
            }
}
```

Comment: I hope you have, `<context:component-scan base-package="your.package.CustomerController"/>` in your Spring Configuration file.